# Are there disadvantages of using large number of entities in Azure ServiceBus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, servicebus

In another words, if I create messaging layout which uses rather large number of messaging entities (like several thousands), instead of smaller number, is there something in Azure ServiceBus that gets irritated by that and makes it perform less than ideally, or generates significantly different costs. Let us assume that number of messages will remain roughly the same in both scenarios.

So to make clear I am not asking if messaging layout with many entities is sound from applications point of view, but rather is there in Azure some that performs badly in such situations. If there are advantages to it (perhaps Azure can scale it more easily), that would be also interesting.

I am aware of 10000 entites limit in single ServiceBus namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the more matter of programming and architecture of the solution i think - for example, we saw the problems with the ACS (authentication mechanism) - SB started to throttle the client sometimes when there were many requests. [Take a look at the guidance about SB high availability](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-outages-disasters/) - there are some issues listed that should be considered when you have a lot of load.

And, you always have other options that can be more suitable for highload scenarios - for example, Azure Event Hubs, more lightweight queue mechanism intended to be the service for the extremely high amount of messages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand there are many other factors. It is just that in the problem I am looking at solution that has nice decoupling requires larger number of entites, and I am thinking going that way, but I am checking if there are some well know SB weak spots in that direction

Comment: Did you check a link i posted? The majority of the problems and issues i had with SB in terms of what you are saying was connected with hitting the limits. SB is a service that is oriented to be reliable with the large number of entities, so do not hit the limits, and i believe that you will be good to go. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#service-bus-limits

Comment: @AlexBelotserkovskiy provided a good answer. Also think what your topology will be. You could have a large number of entities with a small number of listeners if you build your topology in a different way. Had a post that demonstrates how a topology change can reduce number of connections and reduce chanced to get throttled: https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/choosing-topology-with-azure-service-bus

Comment: relatively large number of entities with auto forward wiring, and few listeners is actually what I am considering. @Alex Belotserkovskiy yes I have looked at that link (even before), and I intend to stay below published limits.

Comment: Awesome. Please the question answered if that was helpful.

Comment: I have already marked your question as helpful, but I will of course wait if there are other opinions before marking question as answered